# What to do with an array element that does not get filled

Tags: java, arrays

I have a loop that will fill an array however when I run the code, it seems to not fill an element. The code is supposed to calculate the volume of concentric shells in a sphere. I Have the radius grid figured out which has the number of elements set as shells + 1 to account for the center point. Now I want to use it in this volume method that will return the same amount of shells as chosen. The only way i can get values if if I initialize the volume grid as [shells + 1]. My return the amount of shell, excluding the extra element. This is great but, I need to use this grid for other calculations. Will this extra, undefined element mess with the other calculations?

```
public class VolGrid  {     
    public double vol[];
    double p = PhysicalConst.pi;

    // Volume on concentric shells
    public VolGrid ( int shells , double radius )
    {   
        RadGrid rg = new RadGrid (shells , radius );

        vol = new double [ shells +1];                  

        for ( int k = 1 ; k <= shells ; k++ ) 
        {   
            vol [ k ] =  ( ( 4.0 / 3 ) * p * ( Math.pow( rg.rad [ k ] , 3 ) - Math.pow( rg.rad [ k-1 ] , 3 ) ) ) ;

            System.out.println(vol[k]); 
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: If i were to start with 0, my equation there would fall:   vol [ k ] =  ( ( 4.0 / 3 ) * p * ( Math.pow( rg.rad [ k ] , 3 ) - Math.pow( rg.rad [ k-1 ] , 3 ) ) ) ;

Comment: Please the **Edit:** of my answer regarding your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Array indices are 0-based. The standard way to iterate over an array of *n* elements is to loop from 0 to *n*-1 rather than from 1 to *n*.

```
vol = new double[shells];                  

for (int k = 0; k < shells; k++) {
    ...
}
```